# Link to a PDF from XML

Tags: xml, flash, pdf

I need to link to a PDF file from inside a XML file which is used by flash.

Any idea how to do this?

```
<review link="http://reviews.cnet.com/laptops/hp-folio-13/4505-3121_7-35096620.html">
    <quote><![CDATA[<b></b>]]></quote>
    <author><![CDATA[January 4, 2012]]></author>
</review>
```

Instead of linking to the HTML page it should link to a PDF file.

Comment: What's wrong with `http://example.com/file.pdf`?

Comment: Alex, you'll need to provide much more information than that. E.g. how is your above XML used by your flash?

Comment: Flash loads the XML to display the information, then the review link should bring to a pdf file which will need to be loaded locally.

Comment: the pdf file is not coming from a URL but it's loaded locally from one of my folders in the server

Comment: How would that work with a link Lukas? file://path of my file?

Comment: Never mind. That won't work over the web, only for you, locally

Comment: ok, yep it has to work over the web :)

Comment: ok sorted guys thanks anyway :)